# How to ignore second hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup

I have a second hard drive in my macbook pro that is bootable into my older os install after installing a new SSD with a clean build of OSX Mavericks. When booted into my SSD, I want my old drive to be only used storage space, however it keeps using it for other things. For example when I press open with, it shows me all my apps from the old drive. I already disabled Spotlight for the old drive, but how can I prevent all function except as an external drive?

PS. I still need to boot into it occasionally and I cant just eject it when using my SSD because I need to access files on it.

Comment: You can try unregistering dirs from Launch Services.
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -u /path/to/dir`

Comment: Not clear to me:( so you want it to be connected but not functional at all, or partially functional or sometimes functional, or ?

Comment: I agree with Buscar웃, please clarify what you are wanting. I was starting to write an answer about using `fstab` to prevent drives from being auto mounted or set to read only. Also, is this internal drive really behaving differently from how an external drive would work?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just want it to work as storage and for the OS not to use it for anything unless I explicitly read or write files on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar configuration. Two physical drives: one Mavericks, the other Mountain Lion as failsafe. When Yosemite comes out, I can leap Mountain Lion ahead.

In your primary OSX, exclude the /oldpartitionname/ (or, /oldpartitionname/Applications) from Spotlight.

Then reset "Open With" menu with Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Your OSX will rebuild a new list of apps, within the newly defined scope.

Comment: I wrote in the question that I already did that

Comment: You didn't say that you did actually reset LaunchService.